# Append a Jade file to a div in parent Jade file on Button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, pug, highcharts-ng

I tried to find solution for the past 3 days but no luck.

My requirement is to **load highcharts** which has some data for analysis. I have **to load 50 such charts with each chart holding a million points**. To get rid of the browser collapse, I decided to load 10 charts at once and give a show more button at the bottom of the page which **onclick** should load another 10 charts on the same page below the existing 10.

**Issue:**

- No idea on how to **append a jade file to a div on a button click
  to the existing jade file**.

**What i did:**

- I have two jade file named jade1to10.jade and jade11to20.jade with
  there respective .js(angular) files for charts configurations.
- I can load them individually on different tabs.
- I tried **Include** option **in jade but that loads on the compile
  time and want the second page to load/append to the parent jade after
  the button click**.

I am using angular controllers in the jade to load charts.
Please give your inputs to find a fix.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but a piece of advice: use `boost.js` module from Highcharts. Otherwise, loading 50charts, each a million of points will kill users browser.. I guess even two or three of such charts could hang out a browser. `boost.js` module renders data on the canvas which is a bit faster (but has some limitations).

Comment: Apart of Pawel suggestion, you can also consider using lazy-loading solution. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading

Comment: Oh Yeah that's very true @PawełFus . I will review that in my case.

Comment: My charts are slow both in loading and responsiveness. Surely i will adopt both of your ideas. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it.

Actually you need to use ajax. When the user clicks the button, then send a ajax request to the server and return the charts in html form to you. Finally just insert them into your div.

To compile the file from jade form into html form, See the following example.

```
var jade = require('jade')
var file = fs.... //onefile, must be a string.
var template = jade.compile(file)
var result = template(locals) //the locals is a object which contains the variables you want to pass to the template. 

....
app('/',function(req,res){
    res.send(result)
)
```

You can also just pass the data to the client, and transform them into which you want then insert into the div. That can reduce the network consumption.

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: hello, thank you for the reply. My problem is i have a jade file(file1.jade) which loads 10 charts(1-10). I have another jade file(file2.jade) which loads 10 more(11-20) charts.  All i want is to load/append the file2.jade  along with the file1.jade. I tried include but that doesn't load the javascript associated with file2.jade. I want file2.jade to be compiled and loaded along with the first. Please help if you have some idea on the same. Thanks again